# Ionic Factory Returning Empty Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I might be trying out something that's not supposed.
Still have not wrapped my head around the whole "Singleton" thing.

The thing is, I have a factory that is support to get some json data from an API.
I am getting an empty object returned from the factory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
.factory('specialities', function($http){
    var specialities = [];
    return {
        getspecialities: function(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://mydomain.abc/Api/specialities",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {    
                specialities = response.data.list;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
            return specialities;
        }  
    }               
})
```

This is my controller.

```
.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'specialities', 'areas', '$timeout',
function ($scope, $stateParams, specialities, areas, $timeout) {
    $scope.specialities = specialities.getspecialities();
    $scope.areas = areas.getareas();
    //console.log($scope.areas);
     $scope.slide = function(){
         console.log($scope.specialities);
         console.log($scope.areas);
     }
     $timeout($scope.slide, 5000);
}])
```

All I get is empty arrays in the console even after the time out.
Please help.

Thank you

----Edit
I'm trying the below code.
Controller

```
.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'specialities', '$timeout', '$state',
function ($scope, $stateParams, specialities,  $timeout, $state) {  
    specialities.getspecialities().then(function(specialities)
    {
       $scope.specialities = specialities;
        console.log($scope.specialities);
    });
}])
```

Factory

```
.factory('specialities', function($http, $q){
    return {
         getspecialities: function(){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://mydomain.abc/Api/specialities",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {    
                return response.data.list;
            });
        } 
    }               
})
```

Now the console never logs and the factory seems to be not called called because the API url is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$http` call is async, and returns a Promise.

Your `return specialities` is executed just after the `$http` call is started, but way before it actually finishes its work.

Change your `getspecialities` function to actually return the return value of `$http` (which is a Promise), and use that promise when calling it.

Service:

```
.factory('specialities', function($http, $q){
    return {
        getspecialities: function(){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://mydomain.abc/Api/specialities",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {    
                return response.data.list;
            };
        }  
    }               
})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'specialities', 'areas', '$timeout',
function ($scope, $stateParams, specialities, areas, $timeout) {
    specialities.getspecialities().then(function(specialities)
    {
       $scope.specialities = specialities;
       ... any other stuff that needs to happen when you receive the value of specialities ...
    });
    ...

}])
```

Comment: I tried the code. But it seems like the factory's function doesn't get called. I have updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Add more logs to see which code paths are executed or not. It's quite possible your `$http` call returns an error (add a second function to each `then` and log what happens there to check).

Comment: I was so excited I actually didn't change the domain name. haha. It's working now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

Controller

```
.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'specialities', '$timeout', '$state',
function ($scope, $stateParams, specialities,  $timeout, $state) {  
    specialities.getspecialities(function(specialities)
    {
       $scope.specialities = specialities;
        console.log($scope.specialities);
    });
}]);
```

Service

```
.factory('specialities', function($http, $q){
    return {
         getspecialities: function(callback){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://mydomain.abc/Api/specialities",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {    
                return callback(response.data.list);
            });
        } 
    }               
})
```